# How to encode a .wmv file that XNA DirectShow will play properly?

Tags: xna, ffmpeg, directshow.net

I'm playing around with XNA DirectShow to stream a video from a file rather than loading it into my project (I'm fully aware of the XNA MediaPlayer class by the way). It plays the sample video it came with no problem. When I try to make my own .wmv from a series of PNG files I have using ffmpeg the video plays but is all blue (should be mostly yellow). Pixel format wrong? Wrong codec? I'm certainly no expert in these waters..

The sample video is a VC-1 WMV3 apparantly, and I don't think I can replicate that? What encoding/codec/fileformat should I be using?

Also! If transparent video background is possible, that would be amazing. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved it - I simply switched the order pixels are assigned to when DirectShow creates its output texture. In the VideoPlayer class I changed UpdateBuffer to:

```
 private void UpdateBuffer()
    {
        int waitTime = avgTimePerFrame != 0 ? (int)((float)avgTimePerFrame / 10000) : 20;

        int samplePosRGBA = 0;
        int samplePosRGB24 = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int y = 0, y2 = videoHeight - 1; y < videoHeight; y++, y2--)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < videoWidth; x++)
                {
                    samplePosRGBA = (((y2 * videoWidth) + x) * 4);
                    samplePosRGB24 = ((y * videoWidth) + x) * 3;

                    //make transparent if pixel matches a certain colour
                    if (WhiteTransparent && bgrData[samplePosRGB24 + 2] > 200 && bgrData[samplePosRGB24 + 1] > 200 && bgrData[samplePosRGB24 + 0] > 200)
                    {
                        //transparent pixel
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 0] = 0;
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 1] = 0;
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 2] = 0;
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 3] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //modified pixel format order - switch the 2,1,0 on the right for other formats..
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 0] = bgrData[samplePosRGB24 + 2];
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 1] = bgrData[samplePosRGB24 + 1];
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 2] = bgrData[samplePosRGB24 + 0];
                        videoFrameBytes[samplePosRGBA + 3] = alphaTransparency;
                    }
                }
            }

            frameAvailable = false;
            while (!frameAvailable)
            { Thread.Sleep(waitTime); }
        }
    }
```

which also displays any white areas as transparent in the final image if a bool I added to the class - WhiteTransparent is true. Crude I know, but it's doing the trick for me. Just use the lines in the else statement if not desired.